# Jupyter kernel dies using coremltools for large decision trees

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, coreml, coremltools

I've trained a model using scikit-learn's DecisionTreeClassifier on a dataset with >3,000,000 rows and 15 features (binary encoding of categories.) It runs nicely and does what I want it to do. When I try to convert it to a CoreML model, it doesn't work. I get "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically." I dropped the size of my data down, and for really small batches, it works fine. It seems to break around 500 rows.

I'm new to using CoreML, and this may be a misunderstanding of how it works, but I'm not sure. I feel like given its purpose, CoreML should be able to handle bigger models with a large number of class labels (I'm looking at around 40,000.)

Any idea on how to fix this issue or work around it?

A simplified idea of what I'm doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import coremltools
import random
import string
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 

X = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(15*1000,), p=[1./3, 2./3])
X = np.split(X,1000)

y = []
for i in range(0,1000):
    x = ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(5))
    y.append(x)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X,y)

d = {'arr': X, 'str': y}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert(clf, "arr", 
    "str") ## kernel dies here for larger data
coreml_model.save('mymodel.mlmodel')
```

**Update:** It's a memory issue (probably.) Once I get past about 2 mb, I get

`malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb096a0f738: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed. *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Debugging just gives

`Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: "binary arrays of length ~15 representing categories"  So, then don't you have 15  features? And why are you doing list of arrays? np.arrays can be 2-dimensional.

Comment: When the kernel dies, it's because Python crashed, or a library used by Python has crashed. In this case, it seems like a bug in coremltools.